# Naming a New Assembly for Application Front End

Tags: assemblies, naming-conventions, naming, frontend

Im after some suggestions for naming a new assembly. The project is a multi-tier rich client app using WPF and we've got good names for all the assemblies (data and business layers) except for the front end.

The assembly in question holds the actual user interface and classes for data binding.

We want it to be something short and descriptive like:

xxx.xxx.UI

xxx.xxx.FrontEnd

xxx.xxx.ViewModel

Unfortunately they're all a bit lame.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Anything that comes to mind.

Thank you!

Comment: Name it after somebody.  xxx.xxx.Winston

Comment: xxx.xxx.View, perhaps?  Does it need InterCaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use.

UI/Presentation Teir = Company.Application(Claims, Underwriting, etc).Module
Business Tier = Comapny.Application.Model
Data Tier = Company.Application.Data
Test Company.Application.Test

So every logical unit has a Model project, Module project, Data Project and Test Project.

Brette